# Connecting Heroku to an existing Rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Im brand new to rails, and i have created a simple application. I now want to connect heroku to my app, but i am unsure if this is possible to do. Am i able to connect an existing application to heroku, or must i start from scratch using [this guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-ruby#deploy-the-app)?

Comment: have you installed `Heroku Toolbelt` in your local machine which would give you access to `Heroku Command Line Interface (CLI)` ?

Comment: Yes. I also have my current application saved to github @dkp

Comment: then just do `heroku create` and `git push heroku master` - this should deploy your app to Heroku. If you are facing any particular issue/error, then add it to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deploy your app to Heroku following the guide. Then you can point your Heroku app to your domain name.